# N|Solid uses 20 GB of RAM

Tags: nsolid

While providing great value for inspecting our Node.js processes, N|Solid also seems to take up a rather large amount of memory across all the processes spawned by itself, around 20 GB. Is it possibly misconfiguration on our part or is memory consumption that high to be expected?

[image: nsolid memory consumption]

Comment: Looks like you are using an N|Solid console with many processes attached and that is causing a lot of overhead, could you please tell us how many processes are you currently monitoring? and for how long you have been running this server?

Comment: @edsadr Hey, thanks for getting back to us so quickly! We are monitoring 1 app with 4 processes, using the Solid|4 license – in the console, it also says "Number of Processes (4)". Host uptime is around 150 days, but N|Solid has been installed on this server for only a couple of days. Runtime version is 4.9.4. Tracing is off. Metrics interval is 3000ms.

Comment: It is an odd case indeed. Would it be possible to get access to this Console's logs? we need to analyze what is happening; also, if you are monitoring just 4 processes, wouldn't it be better for you to use our free plan in our SaaS service?